# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.Getting data from one collection and adding it to another

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In my firestore, i have a creators collection created and i am trying to create an edit profile collection. i want to get the value of a field in the creators collection and add it to the edit profile collection. After some research, i found out a way to go about doing this but when i want to set the value to the field, i get the error above. I would really appreciate some help.
here is the code

```
 editProfile()async{
    CollectionReference creatorCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Creators');
    CollectionReference editProfileCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('EditProfile');
    String profileImageUrl =await uploadProfilePictureToStorage(_image);
    String profilePicUrl =await uploadProfilePictureToStorage(_profilePic);
    creatorCollection.where("fullName", isEqualTo: widget.enterName).get().then((querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) {
        final DocumentSnapshot creatorDoc = result;
        editProfileCollection.doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).set({
        'FullName': creatorDoc.data()?["fullName"],
        'EditedFullName': _name,
        'location': _location,
        'links': _linked,
        'contact':_contact,
        'dob':_dob,
        'uid':FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
        'likes':[],
        'Headers': profileImageUrl,
        'ProfilePic':profilePicUrl
        }).whenComplete((){
          Navigator.pop(context);
        });
      });
    });
```

what i am trying to get from the creators collection is the fullname. If there is a better way to go about getting the value, that would also be appreciated. Here is the collection by the way

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.get` or use `as Map?` like `'FullName': (creatorDoc.data() as Map?)?["fullName"],`

```dart
'FullName': creatorDoc.get("fullName"),
```